# [Chrome extension]How to add contextmenu when Tab area click?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I create chrome extension.
So, I want to add menu for right click at Tab area.
Is this possible?
I check following site, and set {contexts: ["all"]}, but not appear my menu when right click at Tab area.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#type-ContextType

Comment: No, not possible. See https://crbug.com/704833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No, not possible. See crbug.com/704833 – wOxxOm Nov 14 at 4:14